# Syncing bookmarks in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, sync, dropbox

I'd love to use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) to sync my [iTerm2](http://sites.google.com/site/iterm2home/) bookmarks, but I can't find the bookmarks file. `~/Library/Application Support/iTerm` only contains a history of commands that have been run, and there is no `/Library/Application Support/iTerm`

Anyone know where these bookmarks are kept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`

Sadly, making a symlink is not sufficient because Apple's library erases it when saving prefs. Could be done with cron and a clever script, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to post -- I found the prefs but noticed that creating a symlink didn't do anything. Ugh.

Comment: Although, looks like I may be able to do the opposite -- post a symlink to the Prefs file into Dropbox so at least I can have an up-to-date copy of it all times. When I move to a different computer I can bring that down and replace my existing one. I don't add bookmarks all that often. I just want to make sure I always have access to the newest list of them.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of iTerm2 support explicitly setting the location of the preferences file, which you can stick in `~/DropBox/Apps/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`and that seems to work fine. The iTerm2 preference is under the "General" tab.